# I am doing this challenge at Leet Code where you should sort array and delete all zeros and it always keeps one zero?

Tags: javascript

```
nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
nums2 = [2,5,6]
var merge = function(nums1,nums2) {
    let deletezeros = function(numi){
        for(let i = 0; i < numi.length; i++){
            if(numi[i] == 0){
                numi.splice(i, 1)
            }
        }
    }
    deletezeros(nums1)
    deletezeros(nums2)
    let result = nums1.concat(nums2)
    result.sort()
    return result
};

let a = merge(nums1,nums2)

console.log(a)
```

result is

```
[
  0, 1, 2, 2,
  3, 5, 6
]
```

Comment: You have a stack of books. You start at the bottom. You pull one out, all the others slide down a spot. You do not look at the one that just filled the void, you move to the next book. So you skip books. Sometimes you get lucky and the book was not a zero, sometimes you get unlucky and the book you skipped was a zero. Plenty of dupes out there. Easiest solution, loop from the end to the start

Comment: `var merge = (x,y) => x.filter(e => e !== 0).concat(y.filter(e => e !==0)).sort()`

Answer (score -1):

Decrement `i` after calling `splice`:

```js
nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
nums2 = [2, 5, 6]
var merge = function(nums1, nums2) {
  let deletezeros = function(numi) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numi.length; i++) {
      if (numi[i] == 0) {
        numi.splice(i, 1)
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
  deletezeros(nums1)
  deletezeros(nums2)
  let result = nums1.concat(nums2)
  result.sort()
  return result
};

let a = merge(nums1, nums2)

console.log(a)
```